# How to start the batch service process?

Tags: batch-file, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

In Dynamics AX 2012, how to automate the Batch jobs to execute at regular interval of time?

I have created a new batch job, for my job I have created the recurrence, so that my job is added in Batch Queue (Batch List) with the regular interval of 5 minutes timings.

But it was in waiting state, it's not coming to executing state. My batch is not executing.

Is their any bug in AX 2012 or is the problem from my side?

Answer (score 3):

(To complete Jan B answer, as I can't comment)

What you need now is a batch server to process your job.
You can find documentation on TechNet :

- [Batch server overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd309586.aspx)
- [Configure an AOS instance as Batch Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg731831.aspx)

You could also use a client instance : [Run client and private batch tasks](http://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/aa551632).

Answer (score 2):

It works!

Check your server configuration (in System administration\Setup\System) whether any AOS is accepting batch, check batch time periods and also check your batch group setup.